# Connect to SQL Server using a pem file, username and password

Tags: sql-server, ssl, iis, connection-string, google-cloud-sql

I have a SQL Server (which is a Google cloud SQL Server). The connection with it needs to be ssl encrypted and authenticated with a username and password.

I can get the `.pem` file for the ssl certificate :

[image]

I also have the username, password, and ip of the server. In the [SqlClient connection string syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) I was able to find the flags defining the username (uid), password (pwd) and ip (Data Source). But I can't find how to place the .pem file.

Does the .pem file not belong in the connection string? If so, how do I use it ?

Thanks,
nimrod

Edit: I tried opening the connection with `trustServerCertificate=true`, but still got `error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server`.

Solution:
The SSL wasn't the issue. Adding the TrustServerCertificate and Encrypt flags should have allowed SSL. With these flags the client just accepts any certificate from the sever, and proceeds with the SSL handshake. 
My issue was that I didn't add the client network to the trusted networks list for the cloud SQL. This is apparently a requirement even though the cloud SQL is set to us a public IP. I added the 0.0.0.0/0 network as trusted, and the connection worked.

Comment: Are you using a [public](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/configure-ip) or [private](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/configure-private-ip) IP address? Either way, there are some extra configuration steps that'll need to be followed (see previous links). You can also try using the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-proxy) which is the recommended way to connect to Cloud SQL.

Comment: Anyway, the error you're seeing, `error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server`, doesn't seem to be an SSL issue. The issue is that you're not reaching the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the .pem file not belong in the connection string?

No.

The client demands protocol encryption using the `Encrypt` [connection string option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). If the server's certificate is not trusted by the client, you either need to install the certificate on the client or opt to `TrustServerCertificate` in the connection string.

Comment: I don't mind trusting the server certificate. But I still can't open the connection. This means its unrelated to the ssl issue ?

Comment: Yep.  Normal connection troubleshooting next.

Comment: I actually tried this before you posted it, but had a different issue, so I thought I misunderstood the docs. Thanks.